# Why does this form a basis for $V$? (Intuitive explanations please)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the space spanned by $\mathbf f_1=\sin(x)$ and $\mathbf f_2=\cos(x)$.

Show that $\mathbf g_1=2\sin(x)+\cos(x$) and $\mathbf g_2=3\cos(x)$ form a basis for $V$.

We can see that $$\mathbf g_1=2\mathbf f_1+\mathbf f_2$$$$\mathbf g_2=0\mathbf f_1+3\mathbf f_2$$

So, $\mathbf g_1$ and $\mathbf g_2$ can be written as a linear combination of $\mathbf f_1$ and $\mathbf f_2$, but I am not sure as to what exactly this is saying.

($1st$ semester in LA).

Comment: What can we say about the matrix $\begin{array}{|cc|}
2 & 1 \\0 & 3
\end{array}$?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at a two dimensional space. Any two vectors that aren't on a line together (ie, aren't proportional to one another) will form a basis, and as you can plainly see by drawing a picture, $(2, 1)$ is not on a line with $(0, 3)$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following:

$$\begin{cases}g_1=2f_1+f_2\\{}\\g_2=3f_3\end{cases}\implies g_1,g_2\in V$$

Since clearly $\;\dim V=2\;$ (why?) , it is then enough to prove $\;\{g_1,g_2\}\;$ is linearly independent, so suppose we have real scalars (I'm assuming the base field is the reals) $\;a,b\;$ s.t.

$$0=ag_1+bg_2=2a\sin x+(a+3b)\cos x$$

The above is a *functional identity*, so it msut be true for any $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ , but then

$$x=0\implies 0=2a\sin 0+(a+3b)\cos 0=a+3b\\x=\frac\pi2\implies 0=2a\sin\frac\pi2+(a+3b)\cos\frac\pi2=2a$$

Thus, we get

$$(2a=0\implies a=0)\implies b=0$$

and we're done.